# jquery match feed urls

Tags: jquery, regex

Hi just wondering how I can match all the rss feed from DOM into an array?

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/qzoim/giving_away_500_copies_of_our_game_dungeon/.rss" />
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var links = [];
$('link[type="application/rss+xml"]').each(function() {
     links.push($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = [];

$("link").each(function(){
    myArray.push(this.href);
});
```

Comment: That would also include the stylesheet link, which is probably more a bug than a feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [];

arr.forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('link[href*=".rss"]'),
    function(el){
        arr.push(el.href);
     }
);
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/H57Kj/)**
    ​

Answer (score 0):

```
var rssLinks = $('link[type="application/rss+xml"]').map(function(i,val) {
    return val.href;
}).get();
```

Comment: what's the dif between each and map? :)

Comment: `.map()` returns an array. From the docs: The .map() method is particularly useful for getting or setting the value of a collection of elements.